# How to add and remove new layers in keras after loading weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to do a transfer learning; for that purpose I want to remove the last two layers of the neural network and add another two layers. This is an example code which also output the same error.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input,Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model

in_img = Input(shape=(3, 32, 32))
x = Convolution2D(12, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='valid', name='conv1')(in_img)
x = Activation('relu', name='relu_conv1')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)
x = Convolution2D(3, 1, 1, border_mode='valid', name='conv2')(x)
x = Activation('relu', name='relu_conv2')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
o = Activation('softmax', name='loss')(x)
model = Model(input=in_img, output=[o])
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
#model.load_weights('model_weights.h5', by_name=True)
model.summary()

model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.summary()
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Activation('sigmoid', name='loss'))
```

I removed the layer using `pop()` but when I tried to add its outputting this error

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'add'
```

I know the most probable reason for the error is improper use of `model.add()`. what other syntax should I use?

**EDIT:**

I tried to remove/add layers in keras but its not  allowing it to be added after loading external weights.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input,Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
in_img = Input(shape=(3, 32, 32))

def gen_model():
    in_img = Input(shape=(3, 32, 32))
    x = Convolution2D(12, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='valid', name='conv1')(in_img)
    x = Activation('relu', name='relu_conv1')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(3, 1, 1, border_mode='valid', name='conv2')(x)
    x = Activation('relu', name='relu_conv2')(x)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    o = Activation('softmax', name='loss')(x)
    model = Model(input=in_img, output=[o])
    return model

#parent model
model=gen_model()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
model.summary()

#saving model weights
model.save('model_weights.h5')

#loading weights to second model
model2=gen_model()
model2.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
model2.load_weights('model_weights.h5', by_name=True)

model2.layers.pop()
model2.layers.pop()
model2.summary()

#editing layers in the second model and saving as third model
x = MaxPooling2D()(model2.layers[-1].output)
o = Activation('sigmoid', name='loss')(x)
model3 = Model(input=in_img, output=[o])
```

its showing this error

```
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor input_4 at layer "input_4". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Comment: This seem similar [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284898/how-to-switch-off-on-an-lstm-layer/54872809 to your question.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can take the `output` of the last model and create a new model. The lower layers remains the same.

```
model.summary()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.summary()

x = MaxPooling2D()(model.layers[-1].output)
o = Activation('sigmoid', name='loss')(x)

model2 = Model(inputs=in_img, outputs=[o])
model2.summary()
```

Check [How to use models from keras.applications for transfer learnig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378461/how-to-use-models-from-keras-applications-for-transfer-learnig/41386444#41386444)

**Update on Edit:**

The new error is because you are trying to create the new model on global `in_img` which is actually not used in the previous model creation.. there you are actually defining a local `in_img`. So the global `in_img` is obviously not connected to the upper layers in the symbolic graph. And it has nothing to do with loading weights.

To better resolve this problem you should instead use `model.input` to reference to the input.

```
model3 = Model(input=model2.input, output=[o])
```

Comment: In Keras 2.4.0, the keywords for keras.model.Model are "inputs" and "outputs" rather than "input" and "output"

Answer (score 39):

Another way to do it

```
from keras.models import Model

layer_name = 'relu_conv2'
model2= Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model1.get_layer(layer_name).output)
```

Answer (score 37):

As of Keras 2.3.1 and TensorFlow 2.0, `model.layers.pop()` is not working as intended (see issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479#issuecomment-424577448)). They suggested two options to do this.

One option is to recreate the model and copy the layers. For instance, if you want to remove the last layer and add another one, you can do:

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in source_model.layers[:-1]: # go through until last layer
    model.add(layer)
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

Another option is to use the functional model:

```
predictions = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(source_model.layers[-2].output)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

`model.layers[-1].output` means the last layer's output which is the final output, so in your code, you actually didn't remove any layers, you added another head/path.

Comment: Iterating through the layers and adding them to a sequential model does not work when your original model is not linear. It's better to create a copy of your original model and directly change it there.

Answer (score 28):

An alternative to Wesam Na's answer, if you don't know the layer names you can simply cut off the last layer via:

```python
from keras.models import Model

model2= Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model1.layers[-2].output)
```

Comment: This page is a chain of great answers updating over time

Comment: @alex your answer is simple and great. Why not completing it with showing how to add the new layers?