# Replace stride layers in MobileNet application in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, mobilenet

I would like to apply in `Keras` `MobileNetV2` on images of size `39 x 39` to classify `3` classes. My images represent heat maps (e.g. what keys have been pressed on the keyboard). I think `MobileNet` was designed to work on images of size `224 x 224`. I will not use transfer learning but train the model from scratch.

To make `MobileNet` work on my images, I would like to replace the first three stride `2` convolutions with stride `1`. I have the following code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2

base_model = MobileNetV2(weights=None, include_top=False, 
                         input_shape=[39,39,3])
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output_tensor = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
cnn_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output_tensor)

opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
cnn_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
             optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

How can I replace the first three stride `2` convolutions with stride `1` without building `MobileNet` myself?

Comment: why not resizing the images?

Comment: @SoheilStar When resizing the images, it is less efficient (bigger images, so runtime and memory consumption grows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one workaround for your need but I think probably it's possible to have a more general approach. However, in the `MobileNetV2`, there is only one `conv` layer with `strides 2`. If you follow the source code, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2.py#L301-L312)

```
 x = layers.Conv2D(
      first_block_filters,
      kernel_size=3,
      strides=(2, 2),
      padding='same',
      use_bias=False,
      name='Conv1')(img_input)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(
      axis=channel_axis, epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name='bn_Conv1')(
          x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name='Conv1_relu')(x)
```

And the rest of the blocks are defined as follows

```
  x = _inverted_res_block(
      x, filters=16, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=1, block_id=0)
  x = _inverted_res_block(
      x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=1)
  x = _inverted_res_block(
      x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=2)
```

So, here I will deal with the **first `conv`** with **`stride=(2, 2)`**. The idea is simple, we will **add a new layer in the right place of the built-in model and then remove the desired layer**.

```
def _make_divisible(v, divisor, min_value=None):
    if min_value is None:
        min_value = divisor
    new_v = max(min_value, int(v + divisor / 2) // divisor * divisor)
    # Make sure that round down does not go down by more than 10%.
    if new_v < 0.9 * v:
        new_v += divisor
    return new_v
alpha = 1.0
first_block_filters = _make_divisible(32 * alpha, 8)

inputLayer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(39, 39, 3), name="inputLayer")
inputcOonv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                first_block_filters,
                kernel_size=3,
                strides=(1, 1),
                padding='same',
                use_bias=False,
                name='Conv1_'
        )(inputLayer)
```

The above `_make_divisible` function simply derived from the source code. Anyway, now we impute this layer to the `MobileNetV2` right before the first `conv` layer, as follows:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights=None, 
                            include_top=False, 
                            input_tensor = inputcOonv)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output_tensor = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
cnn_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output_tensor)
```

Now, if we observe

```
for i, l in enumerate(cnn_model.layers):
    print(l.name, l.output_shape)
    if i == 8: break

inputLayer [(None, 39, 39, 3)]
Conv1_ (None, 39, 39, 32)
Conv1 (None, 20, 20, 32)
bn_Conv1 (None, 20, 20, 32)
Conv1_relu (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_depthwise (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_depthwise_BN (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_depthwise_relu (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_project (None, 20, 20, 16)
```

Layer name `Conv1_` and `Conv1` are the new layer (with `strides = 1`) and old layer (with `strides = 2`) respectively. And as we need, now we remove layer `Conv1` with `strides = 2` as follows:

```
cnn_model._layers.pop(2) # remove Conv1

for i, l in enumerate(cnn_model.layers):
    print(l.name, l.output_shape)
    if i == 8: break

inputLayer [(None, 39, 39, 3)]
Conv1_ (None, 39, 39, 32)
bn_Conv1 (None, 20, 20, 32)
Conv1_relu (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_depthwise (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_depthwise_BN (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_depthwise_relu (None, 20, 20, 32)
expanded_conv_project (None, 20, 20, 16)
expanded_conv_project_BN (None, 20, 20, 16)
```

---

Now, you have `cnn_model` model with `strides = 1` on its first `conv` layer. However, in case you're wondering about this approach and possible issue, please see my other answer related to this one. [Remove first N layers from a Keras Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67180315/9215780)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see five strides 2. There are four inverted res blocks with stride 2, see `x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=1)`. How can I also change these to stride 1?

Comment: So, you want to make `stride = 2 to 1` for all cases? The above workaround is more like a **layer-space** solution (modify layer) rather than a **hyperparameter-space** (strides, padding, etc). AFAIK, there is **no feasible way** to do so without disclosing much enough of the pre-trained model. So, instead, I would simply recommend get the relevant source code and modify as your needs.