# Removing rescaling layer from a functional model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is there a way to remove a rescaling layer from a functional model?

I'm trying to remove the rescaling layer from this model:

```
efficientnetb0_model.layers[0:10]
```

Output:

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer at 0x18d5e873d90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing.Rescaling at 0x18d5e8a2d00>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.normalization.Normalization at 0x18d5eb48100>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.ZeroPadding2D at 0x18d5eb48550>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x18d5eb7f670>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization at 0x18d5eba2c70>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Activation at 0x18d5eb481f0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.DepthwiseConv2D at 0x18d5ebe8e50>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization at 0x18d5ec08e20>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Activation at 0x18d5ec2f1c0>]
```

I tried this:

```
efficientnetb0_model.layers.pop(1)
efficientnetb0_model.layers[0:10]
```

But nothing happens:

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer at 0x18d5e873d90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing.Rescaling at 0x18d5e8a2d00>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.normalization.Normalization at 0x18d5eb48100>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.ZeroPadding2D at 0x18d5eb48550>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x18d5eb7f670>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization at 0x18d5eba2c70>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Activation at 0x18d5eb481f0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.DepthwiseConv2D at 0x18d5ebe8e50>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization at 0x18d5ec08e20>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Activation at 0x18d5ec2f1c0>]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add and remove new layers in keras after loading weights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668813/how-to-add-and-remove-new-layers-in-keras-after-loading-weights)

Comment: @DominikFicek unfortunately, no. If my understanding is right, that question answers adding and removing the last layers. Mine is about removing intermediate layers.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way to remove the intermediate `Rescaling` layer. But, by modifying the `scale` parameter of the `Rescaling` layer, we can nullify the transformation made by the layer.

This can be done by setting `scale` to 1. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Rescaling#args) for the `scale` argument.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0( weights='imagenet' , include_top=False )
print( model.layers )

# 2nd layer in EfficientNetB0
print( model.layers[ 1 ].scale )
```

The output is,

```
0.00392156862745098
```

By setting the `scale` parameter to 1.0,

```
model.layers[ 1 ].scale = 1.0
print( model.layers[ 1 ].scale )
```

Comment: A neat trick ;)