# Can I remove layers in a pre-trained Keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm importing a pre-trained VGG model in Keras, with

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
```

I've noticed that the type of a standard model is `keras.models.Sequential`, while a pre-trained model is `keras.engine.training.Model`. I usually add and remove layers with `add` and `pop` for sequential models respectively, however, I cannot seem to use `pop` with pre-trained models.

Is there an alternative to `pop` for these type of models?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378461/how-to-use-models-from-keras-applications-for-transfer-learnig/41386444#41386444

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're wanting to remove. If you want to remove the last softmax layer and use the model for transfer learning, you can pass the `include_top=False` kwarg into the model like so:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
IN_SHAPE = (256, 256, 3) # image dimensions and RGB channels

pretrained_model = VGG16(
  include_top=False,
  input_shape=IN_SHAPE,
  weights='imagenet'
)
```

I wrote a blog post on this use case recently that has some code examples and goes into a bit more detail: http://innolitics.com/10x/pretrained-models-with-keras/

If you're wanting to modify the model architecture more than that, you can access the `pop()` method via `pretrained_model.layers.pop()`, as is explained in the link @indraforyou posted.

Side note: When you're modifying layers in a pretrained model, it can be especially helpful to have a visualization of the structure and input/output shapes. `pydot` and `graphviz` is particularly useful for this:

```
import pydot
pydot.find_graphviz = lambda: True
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='../model_pdf/{}.pdf'.format(model_name))
```